# Progress Bar value is not updating

Tags: java, swing, awt, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

Here runQuery() function executes a query on 4 databases. I want tprogrssBar value should be updated to 50 on screen before it starts running runQuery() function. But screen gets updated after runQuery() is executed.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String s = e.getActionCommand();
        progressBar.setValue(50);
        runQuery();
    }
```

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: Also, simply searching on [java swing why jprogressbar not updating](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+why+jprogressbar+not+updating) will bring you the answer.